# File format for Macos Finder Alias File Version 3

Tags: macos, finder

I'm trying to read the LoginItems preferences file to change a Network Volume a user has in their login items.  Which mounts when they log in.

I can read the login items using NSUserDefaults and getting it as an NSDictionary.  The problem is that the volume mount details are stored as binary data.  The data appears to be an Alias file format except it's missing the header: `62 6F 6F 6B 00 00 00 00 6D 61 72 6B 00 00 00 00`

I've tried using the current `NSURL resourceValuesForKeys:fromBookmarkData:` but it did not return the remote share.  I realised that the machine they were created on is a 10.6 machine and these calls were only made available in 10.11.

So I tried using the old deprecated Core Carbon libraries `PTRToHand` and `FSCopyAliasInfo` to get information out of this file but all it says is that it is an Alias pointing to `/Volumes/ShareMount` and makes no mention of which server it is trying to connect to.

The binary data does show the string smb mount for the server.

```
0000000: 0000 0000 00a0 0003 0001 0000 0000 0000  ................
0000010: 0000 4244 6375 0001 ffff ffff ffff ffff  ..BDcu..........
0000020: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1201 fffe 0000  ................
0000030: 0000 0000 0000 ffff ffff 000e 000a 0004  ................
0000040: 006d 0061 0072 006b 000f 000a 0004 006d  .m.a.r.k.......m
0000050: 0061 0072 006b 0012 0000 0013 000d 2f56  .a.r.k......../V
0000060: 6f6c 756d 6573 2f6d 6172 6b00 0009 002b  olumes/mark....+
0000070: 002b 6369 6673 0000 0100 0000 736d 623a  .+cifs......smb:
0000080: 2f2f 6d61 726b 4031 302e 3130 312e 3232  //mark@10.101.22
0000090: 322e 3138 352f 6d61 726b 0000 ffff 0000  2.185/mark......
```

I've compared this data with the wikipedia article on Macos Aliases and a python module that reads aliases both of them spcify the version number should be 2, however the byte in this position (byte 6) is 3, after this byte the binary compatibility between the two no longer match.

Does anyone know about this Version 3 Alias format?

I've found two web pages that seem to document the exact same problem I'm having;

One only available via wayback:  [Reversing Mac Alias v3 Data Objects](https://web.archive.org/web/20170222235430/http://sysforensics.org/2016/08/mac-alias-data-objects/) He has only parsed 1 file here and an SMB mount one is slightly different.

[Apple's Bookmark Data Exposed](https://michaellynn.github.io/2015/10/24/apples-bookmarkdata-exposed/) Pretty much describes the steps that I have followed myself to end up asking this question.

Thanks

Comment: Did you then not proceed to try `resourceValuesForKeys:fromBookmarkData:`? Modern APIs should still work with old formats.

Comment: Oh I had proceeded with that but did not get the remote server address.  I assumed this was due to that call not being available on 10.6 as I got minimal data from that call, sorry my mistake.  I also tried using `CFURLCreateBookmarkDataFromAliasRecord` and `CFURLCreateResourcePropertiesForKeysFromBookmarkData` but again the remote url is missing.

Comment: I have since discovered that these files are undocumented and exist in CoreServicesInternal framework, which is in /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/  found all this hidden internal stuff here; https://michaellynn.github.io/2015/10/24/apples-bookmarkdata-exposed/

Comment: You never said what resource keys you tried to get values for. Did you try `NSURLVolumeURLForRemountingKey`?

Comment: There are 112 keys in the NSURL header and 103 keys in CFURL. I've tried every one of them.